# Como guardar registos nas tabelas quando elas têm foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A minha base de dados tem 6 tabelas:

--Movies table

```
MovieID int PK,
MovieName varchar(50)
MovieDescription text,
MovieCategory varchar(50),
MovieYear varchar(4),
ParticipationID)
```

--Series table

```
SeriesData (
SeriesID int PK,
SeriesName varchar(50),
SeriesDescription text,
SeriesCategory varchar(50),
SeriesYear varchar(4),
ParticipationId int FK);
```

--Actors Table

```
ActorsData (
ActorID int PK,
ActorName varchar(50),
ActorAge varchar(3),
ParticipationId int FK)
```

--SeasonsnEpisodes Serve para responder à pergunta "Quantos episodios tem cada temporada"

```
SeasonsEpisodes (
SerieID int PK,
SerieSeasons int,
SerieEpisodes int)
```

--MoviesParticipated  Esta tabela serve para saber em quais filmes o actor participa e que atores participam num certo filme

```
MoviesParticipated (
ParticipationId int PK
ActorID int FK
MovieID varchar(50) FK)
```

--SeriesParticipated  Esta tabela serve para saber em quais filmes o actor participa e que atores participam num certo filme

```
SeriesParticipated (
ParticipationId int PK
ActorID int FK
SeriesID varchar(50) FK)
```

Quando tento adicionar registos dá-me erro por causa das foreign keys. Como adiciono registos nas tabelas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando existe um campo `Forgeign Key` o registro só pode ser criado se o valor desse campo for condizente com o campo referenciado.

Ex:
Imagine uma tabela `Pedido` que possui um campo FK `IdCliente` referenciando `Cliente.Id` (campo `id` da tabela `cliente`)

Você só pode adicionar no campo `Pedido.IdCliente` um Id que existe de fato na `Cliente.Id`.

---

**EDIT**

Agora que postou a modelagem, pude ver que é a primeira opção que disse nos comentários: precisa rever a modelagem.

Você disse que `MoviesParticipated` serve pra informar qual ator participa em qual filme. Ou seja, ela é uma tabela intermediária de uma ligação `n-n` entre `Movies` e `Actors`. (o mesmo vale pra `SeriesParticipated`)

Sendo assim, não precisa referenciar ela como `FK` em outras tabelas, pode remover a FK referente a ela

Comment: Ou seja, como todas as tabelas têm foreign keys, eu nao consigo adicionar registos. Aí está um problema... Eu vou editar a pergunta para ver se me consegue ajudar com alguma coisa

Comment: Se houver referencia circular, terá que rever a modelagem e remover uma ou mais FKs (Ex: tabela1 tem FK apontando pra tabela2, que tem FK apontando pra tabela3, que tem FK pra tabela1)
Se não for o caso, tem que começar dando insert na tabela que não depende de nenhuma outra. Ex: Se `ItemPedido` depende de `Pedido` que depende de `Cliente`, tem que primeiro dar insert na `Cliente`, depois `Pedido`, então na `ItemPedido`

Comment: Editei a resposta :)

Comment: Então eu preciso de remover a FK ParticipationID? ou tiro as 3?

Comment: Pode tirar as 3. A tabela `MoviesParticipated` é dependente dessas outras, mas não deve ser "dependida" por ninguém.